# How to create Custom Path definitions and Filters for Website Sections in Omniture (SiteCatalyst)?

Tags: javascript, reporting, aggregation, web-analytics, adobe-analytics

I tried every possible way for me to understand to do this.

I have a site which accepts only registered users. When a user registers, we get his/her Department, Role, Name and Region. What I am hoping that when this user visits the site, the omniture shows all his credentials (name, role, department, region) along with generic variables like Page views, country, etc.

The report I mentioned in the previous paragraph is needed for the whole site + individual sections of the site. I have three sections in the site (Newsletter, Events and About). I am hoping to get individual reporting for all these three sections + global site reports.

### Update 1

I am extremely indebted to Chris de Groot and Crayon Violent for their help. I have summarized my problem and thought may be I could be post an update. The problem set is actually smaller now:

[image: Problem]

The thing I have to achieve is:

- Get Normal Traffic Variables for the Newsletter Section of the site (Page Views, Vis­its and Unique Vis­i­tors in a mean­ing­ful way)
- See all registered users of my site who visited the Newsletter and categorize them based on their Role, Region

I have all the attributes of the user (Role, Department, Region etc) stored in the DB. Here is what I did up until now.

**On the Newsletter Page**, I used the following code:

```
    s.pageName= document.title.split(" | ") [0];

    s.server=""
    s.channel="Newsletter"
    s.pageType=""
    s.prop1="Newsletter Issue of December"

    /* Conversion Variables */

    s.eVar1="Newsletter Issue of December"
    s.eVar2="Name of the User"
    s.eVar3="Role of the User"
    s.eVar4="Region of the User"
    s.eVar5=""
    s.events = "event2";
```

My question is:

- Is this the right approach for the things I need
- How would I make sure that the Reports in SiteCatalyst are formatted/layouted in the way I want them.

Comment: If you want to see that info in your reports, you must populate SiteCatalyst variables with that data.  For example, assign an eVar and prop for each one and populate them with that value on the page.

Comment: Thank you Crayon. When I populate eVar and prop variable in my report, it'll automatically categorize them the way I want them to be? How'd I categorize them? Do you also know a good tutorial read for eVars and prop implementation? Thanks.

Comment: No, you will need to also assign your categories as well. For example, pop s.channel and a prop and eVar with your category value. Then the categories will be available in various reports, and you can break things down by them or visa versa.  Have you read the implementation manual at all?

Comment: Hi Crayon, Unfortunately, I did go through manual but I guess my knowledge is still quite limited. I'd be thankful if you could help in some way.

Comment: Well what have you tried? The actual Omniture/SC implementation is little more than basic copy/paste, basic javascript.  You copy/paste the on-page code to every page you want to track. Then in the custom code section, you add the variable and populate it with the value. The trick is getting the correct value. How you populate the variable depends on your website, how that data is exposed (or if it's not exposed, then finding a way to expose it). For example, how is the site structure exposed on your site? Is it in your url structure somewhere? In a cookie?

Comment: Maybe you should hire a coder to implement this for you? If you can afford SiteCatalyst then you can certainly afford to hire a freelancer.. nothin' wrong in not knowing how to code, but you're going to be hard pressed to bluff your way through implementation beyond just putting the basic on-page coding on your site, without coding experience.

Comment: Hi Crayon, I thankful for your help and the problem is that I am the one who has to develop. I usually develop JS, PHP and iOS applications and the people around thought that I can do this too. I really wanna do this and I want to learn. I am so sorry for asking the stupid questions. The site is made in Drupal and I can access all the variables correctly in any way I want. It's just the way I've to send them to Omniture. I've now updated my question based on the feedback I understood here and I'll be grateful if you can take a look. (It's in the update on the question above)

Comment: Simple things should be fairly simple in Adobe Analytics. If you have some experience with the Analytic concept then the differences are fairly easy to grasp.

The best way to move forward is if you have the Analytics implementation sending in data, once that is working then you can figure a lot out with trial and error and reading. 

Crayon is right, that hiring an experienced freelancer is the fastest way to a good implementation. But any web developer should be able to get this going with a bit of effort, at least the fundamental reports you are looking to do.

Comment: Assuming you have the analytics events coming through already I suggest you try send in some data and do some trial and error with what you have learnt from this thread.

I think the chart type you are looking for is going to get populated pretty well assuming some things.
eVar1 is named something like “Name of Newsletter” and expires after your event2 (which should have a name like “Newsletter Views”) so you can then capture multiple newsletter views in one visit.

Comment: Give it a go. The chart you will want to see with this implementation will be under Custom Conversion->Custom Conversions 1-10->“Name of Newsletter”. Then add the metric “Newsletter Views” and breakdown by Custom Conversion->Custom Conversions 1-10-> "Name of the User".

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. I really appreciate your answers. I will give it a go and would definitely make sure that I come up with some progress.

Comment: On reflection, given the comments under the question and answer, I wonder if this can be closed as "too broad" now. It seems to be unresolved, still needing extended help, and so I am not sure if it would be of use to many future readers.

Answer (score 2):

The way I think of this is to start with the basics. You can then build many solid reports on top of that.

You need to think of what you want to track and what they are. 
If it is a number it is 95% of the time going to be a metric and thus you need to use *events*. For example "number of **registrations**". 
It you then want to breakdown that number you need dimensions. A dimension is an *eVar*.

So say you wanted to breakdown **registrations** by **department**, you define both variables in your Report Suite Manager (Success Events and Conversion Variables). Then in your web site tagging when a visitor arrives you immediately set the **department** eVar to the department name (it stays set across pages/visits etc, depending on how you configured it earlier in the Report Suite Manager) and after however many pages the user completes registration you set the event for registration.

e.g

```
s.eVar6 = "HR";  // set HR in the department Dimension

/** later **/

s.events = "event3";  // trigger the event for registration. 
                      // This increments the Metric and it is allocated to 
                      // eVar6 and any other currently active eVars.
```

When Adobe Analytics has done its processing you can cut this data many ways. You can for example view a "Custom Conversion" report by **department**(rows) and with the counts of **registration**(columns).

There is a lot to Analytics, it is an awesome tool, it takes years to fully learn, but if you nail the relationship between Metrics and Dimensions you will really be able to do a lot very quickly.

Data like this is in the right format to really allow many reports you want

Ps: The other kind of number in Analytics is an instance. They are really a count of how often an evar was set. If you want to also Path that data then you would use a prop variable (also known as a traffic variable). They are good for simple counts and path analysis.

Comment: Wow Chris, Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I am indebted to you for this. Just a small clarification. If we, for example, consider the Newsletter section. A Newsletter section has lots of Newsletters (Newsletter1, Newsletter2, ...) and user can access them individually to read. Here if I want to track every user who visits the Newsletter section and click on any Newsletter, how would I have variables set?  Would we have `s.channel = Newsletter`, s.eVar1 = "Newsletter1" (when Newsletter1 is opened), s.events = "event4" (when Newsletter1 is opened)? Please assist here.

Comment: @Steve you have invested a lot of money in SiteCatalyst already.. I highly advise you hire a real coder to implement this for you, ideally someone who has SiteCatalyst implementation experience. Not that there aren't knowledgeable people here, but you aren't going to get your money's worth out of SiteCatalyst by fishing for free help on sites like this. Adobe offers help through them and through partners. There's a big difference between asking a random more or less isolated question vs. trying to do a full implementation..

Comment: Crayon/Chris, I posted a comment in my question, please take a look.